# How to create a library from boost?

Tags: linux, boost, llvm

I am using part of boost for a project (only the message_queue). If I use native code, the hpp file is fine. But I need the message queue in a LLVM bitcode file (I'm executing the bitcode in my program) and get the following error:

```
LLVM ERROR: Program used external function 'shm_unlink' which could not be resolved!
```

I was told that building a library with the required part of boost is the best way to solve this problem.

What I did (in the boost directory):

```
gcc -I . -c boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp -o ipc.o
ar -cvq libipc.a ipc.o
ranlib libipc.a
```

and then in my program directory:

```
llvm-g++ -Wall -O3 -static -L../../Release/lib -lipc -I../../include -I../../../boost_1_44_0 -fexceptions -emit-llvm tmp.cpp -o tmp.bc
```

Now, if I include the boost-header in my program, I get:

```
../../Release/lib/libipc.a: could not read symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one
```

If I don't include them, I get a some of errors which are all related to message_queue being undeclared.

What am I doing wrong? And more important, how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shm_unlink, iirc, is provided in the realtime library librt.  Add the link [gcc flag -lrt] to your build